# Keyword Replacement using str_replace and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find certain words in a string and replace them with links to pages

I have three arrays which are like this (this is just an example not the actual thing :P)

```
$string = "Oranges apples pears Pears <p>oranges</p>";
$keyword = array('apples', 'pears', 'oranges');
$links = array('<a href="apples.php">Apples</a>', '<a href="pears.php">Pears</a>', '<a href="oranges.php">Oranges</a>');
$content = str_replace($keyword, $links, $string);
echo $content;
```

It replaces some of the words but not all of them, that is because there are spaces infront of some words and at the end of some words and some are capitalised etc.

I was wondering what is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do. I also tried preg_replace but I am not too good with regex.

Comment: to solve the capitalization problem: [str_ireplace](http://php.net/str_ireplace)

Comment: cheers will do that, any ideas on the spacing?

Comment: I don't see a spacing problem.

Comment: That seemed to work with the spacing also, but another problem has now appeared, if I wanted to replace the word 'apple' with a link it will also replace the word 'apples' but not link the 's', anyway to fix this?

Comment: for that you'll need a regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/str_ireplace):

```
$string = "Oranges apples pears Pears <p>oranges</p>";
$keyword = array('apples', 'pears', 'oranges');
$links = array('<a href="apples.php">Apples</a>', '<a href="pears.php">Pears</a>', '<a href="oranges.php">Oranges</a>');
$content = str_ireplace($keyword, $links, $string);
echo $content;
```

There should be no problem with spaces. for str_replace it doesn't if there is a space before/after the search term or not.

If you only want to replace whole words then you need to use an regular expression:

```
$string = "Oranges apples pear Pears <p>oranges</p>";
$keyword = array('apples', 'pear', 'oranges'); // note: "pear" instead of "pears"
$links = array('<a href="apples.php">Apples</a>', '<a href="pears.php">Pears</a>', '<a href="oranges.php">Oranges</a>');
$content = preg_replace(array_map(function($element) {
    $element = preg_quote($element);
    return "/\b{$element}\b/i";
}, $keyword), $links, $string);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how would I go about replacing for say the word 'apple' and not the word 'apples' ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use str_ireplace function - it is not case-sensitive variant of str_replace function